# How to replace path when navigating to other page using javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need one help.here i need suppose user is currently present in profile page(`http://localhost/medilink/profile.php`).When user will click on only one button the `profile.php` will replace with `deal.php` and the respective page will come.I need this type scenario using click event and change the URL get the new page.Please help me.

Comment: Simple hyperlink like `<a href='deal.php'>Go to Deals</a>` is not working for you ?

Comment: i know that but i want to set this dynamically.

Comment: What is it that you want to set dynamically ? Be clear about your intent

Answer (score 2):

You can add this to your button :

```
// set the proper url

// relative path :
onclick="window.location.href = './deal.php'"
// absolute path :
onclick="window.location.href = '/medilink/deal.php'"
// other website :
onclick="window.location.href = '//google.com"
```

#### Example

your button ("a" tag ? or "button" tag ?) becomes :

```
<button onclick="window.location.href = './deal.php'">my Button</button>
```

Comment: @ Apolo: if localhost or medilink will me change some day i have to set this again again.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function and pass the url you want to redirect.

// JS:

```
function redirectURL(url) {
  window.location.href(url)
}
```

// HTML:

```
<button onclick="changeURL('http://www.gooogle.com')"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code snippet may help you.

```js
$('button').click(function () {
    var arr = window.location.href.split('/');
    arr[arr.length - 1] = 'deal.php';            
    var url = arr.join('/');
  
    window.location = url;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click here</button>
```

Comment: you update your href attribute each time you click ? See relative links, it avoid wrinting this piece of code